# System will not resolve domain.local websites

Tags: networking, dns

I have done a brand new installation of the Ubuntu server (v12.10) with bind configured to have a dns zone of gdos.local and apache configured for said domain.

With a brand new installation of Ubuntu desktop LTS I try to connect to www.gdos.local and all I get is:

Server not found
          Firefox can't find the server at www.gdos.local.
          Check the address for typing errors such as 
          ww.example.com instead of www.example.com

However if I change the domain to gdos.tmp and type in www.gdos.tmp, I get the internal website. If I change it to mybusiness.local , I get the same error message.

If I use a Microsoft os, this works fine, all three domains resolve to a webpage.
I have searched the internet flat for the past week on dns issues but have not come up with a solution.

I have followed instructions from removing dnsmasq to editing like resolv.conf (in some very strange places) and I still have no joy on getting the .local domain extension to work.

I can safely say the issue is not with the server but with the desktops because if the issue was server related the Microsoft OS's would not resolve it either.

I have done several installs of the desktop in an effort to make sure that I did not break anything while trying to fix this.

Please can anyone point to a workable solution for fixing the .local domain extension.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is to use something other than .local.

.local is used by Avahi by default; Avahi is the GPL implementation of Zeroconf -- see the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_%28software%29).

There's a brief guide [here](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/resolving-local-ubuntu-38861.html) which describes reconfiguring avahi-daemon to use something other than .local. You'd need to do this on all your Ubuntu desktops.

Other possibilities are not to run avahi-daemon or to change `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to remove references to mdns.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried any of the above.